# Sending large file to PIPE input in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
sourcefile = open(filein, "r")
targetfile = open(pathout, "w")

content= sourcefile.read():

p = Popen([SCRIPT], stdout=targetfile, stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(content)

sourcefile.close()
targetfile.close()
```

The data in sourcefile is quite large, so it takes a lot of memory/swap to store it in 'content'. I tried to send the file directly to stdin with stdin=sourcefile, which works except the external script 'hangs', ie: keeps waiting for an EOF. This might be a bug in the external script, but that is out of my control for now..

Any advice on how to send the large file to my external script?

Comment: It's very strange that external script hangs if you provide file descriptor directly. Does it also hang when you run it from the terminal: `script < infile > outfile` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `p.communicate(content)` with a loop which reads from the `sourcefile`, and writes to `p.stdin` in blocks. When `sourcefile` is EOF, make sure to close `p.stdin`.

```
sourcefile = open(filein, "r")
targetfile = open(pathout, "w")

p = Popen([SCRIPT], stdout=targetfile, stdin=PIPE)
while True:
    data = sourcefile.read(1024)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    p.stdin.write(data)
sourcefile.close()
p.stdin.close()

p.wait()
targetfile.close()
```